# How to query data from mongoDB which column is an array

Tags: mongodb

{
  "name": "Grieg And Sibelius Songs",
  "status": 1,
  "lastupdate": 1306294550,
  "intro": "",
  "artist": [
    "ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf02",
    "ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf0x"
  ],
  "publisher": "(Warner Music)",
  "release_date": "2006-05-08"

## }

I want to find the the data that artist column "ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf02" in array("ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf02","ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf0d","ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf0r")  what should I　do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $exists to check the presence of the item in array,

```
db.yourcollectionname.find({artist: {$exists:'ar9341cd00668311e0a45217d9fa59cf02'}})
```